# Is there any way to use .net 5.0 nuget package with .net 4.5.1?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package, .net-framework-version, nuget-spec

I've made a custom nuget package from .net 5.0 standard library. Is there any possible solution to Install this nuget with .net framework 4.5.1? This is the error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTGN9.png)

Comment: [.NET Framework 4.5.1 support ended in January 2016](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) - that's 6 years ago. Why not update to the latest version of .NET Framework and then use .NET Standard, which is the usual method of sharing libraries across .NET Framework/.NET Core/.NET 5+

Comment: No, you can't reference a .NET 5.0 NuGet package from .NET Framework 4.5.1. But as mason suggested, you should update to a supported version of .NET Framework and try to use .NET Standard 2.0